# Inform me when site (server) is online again

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols

When I ping one site it returns "Request timed out". I want to make little program that will inform me (sound beep or something like that) when this server is online again. No matter in which language. I think it should be very simple script with a several lines of code. So how to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the notify sound like *echo"^G"*! Just to be different - here's Windows batch:

```
C:\> more pingnotify.bat
:AGAIN
ping -n 1 %1%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO AGAIN
sndrec32 /play /close "C:\Windows\Media\Notify.wav"

C:\> pingnotify.bat localhost
```

:)

Answer (score 3):

Some implementations of ping allow you to specify conditions for exiting after *receipt* of packets:

On Mac OS X, use `ping -a -o $the_host`

- `ping` will keep trying (by default)
- `-a` means beep when a packet is received
- `-o` means exit when a packet is received

On Linux (Ubuntu at least), use `ping -a -c 1 -w inf $the_host`

- `-a` means beep when a packet is received
- `-c 1` specifies the number of packets to send before exit (in this case 1)
- `-w inf` specifies the deadline for when ping exits no matter what (in this case Infinite)
- when `-c` and `-w` are used together, `-c` becomes number of packets **received** before exit

Either can be chained to perform your next command, e.g. to ssh into the server as soon as it comes up (with a gap between to allow `sshd` to actually start up):

```
# ping -a -o $the_host && sleep 3 && ssh $the_host
```

Comment: Is `-o` a standard option? I don't see it on Linux or Windows

Comment: Ah, my bad.  It seems to only be avail on mac.  I guess he can wrap it in a loop.

Comment: Confirm that `-o` is not available on Linux. Too bad, would be very handy for this use. +1 anyhow for showing me the option on my Mac. =)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to run `ping` is a loop, e.g.

```
while ! ping -c 1 host; do sleep 1; done
```

(You can redirect the output to `/dev/null` if you want to keep it quiet.)

On some systems, such as Mac OS X, `ping` may also have the options `-a -o` (as per another answer) available which will cause it to keep pinging until a response is received. However, the `ping` on many (most?) Linux systems does not have the `-o` option and the kind of equivalent `-c 1 -w 0` still exits if the network returns an error.

Edit: If the host does not respond to ping or you need to check the availability of service on a certain port, you can use netcat in the zero I/O mode:

```
while ! nc -w 5 -z host port; do sleep 1; done
```

The `-w 5` specifies a 5 second timeout for each individual attempt. Note that with netcat you can even list multiple ports (or port ranges) to scan when some of them becomes available.

Edit 2: The loops shown above keep trying until the host (or port) is reached. Add your alert command after them, e.g. beep or pop-up a window.